# Re basing in AMCharts

Tags: amcharts

Is it possible for a chart to rebase in `AMCHarts`? If so how? What I did now is asking the chart to recalculate to percents once compared, the only trouble I have now is

> how do I get it to rebase from a 100 and not from 0 or the first
>   datapoint.

Comment: So you basically just want the x-Axis to display other values (from 100%)? Or do you have specific demands? Maybe refer to this [demo](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-data-sets/) and explain a little more.

Comment: Hi Gerric. Ok so what my understanding of rebasing is is that maybe you have values streching from 1 - 7. which then stands as years. meaning 2001; 2002; 2003 and so on. so that's the values, but I want my graph to display from 100. This means that my fist data point wil always be 100. the formula used to do something like that is 1 = 1/1 * 100. Thats how it is explained to me. Now what i did is I converted my Value Axis to change into Percentage once compared to another set of data. for example I want to compare USD with US inflasion @ 3%. Which works.

Comment: But when I compare the first data point starts @ 0 and not at a 100. I want to get it to start at a 100. Always.

Comment: Ok. I'll see what i can do here. One more question: JS Charts or StockCharts?

Comment: JS chart with JSON. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there are different ways to do this:

1. Make your own DataSet with percent values:
   This is pretty much work, but have a lot of control about what you get.
   (e.g. if you wan't specific changes)
2. Change the display values at runtime:
   If you debug your chart, you can see the calculated percent values at this path:
   `chart.valueAxes[valueAxisIndex].data[dataPointIndex].axes[valueAxisId].graphs[graphID].percents.value` this looks more complicated than it is ;)
   You can now iterate through your valueaxes and graphs and add 100 to this value. (The good one with this is, that you neither have to do calculating work, nor changing the source code of amcharts)
3. The last and the **best solution in your case** is to change the calculation in the sources:
   Find `p?k[p]/f*100-100:k[p]` (in amcharts.js) and change it to `p?k[p]/f*100:k[p]`.

> **Note:** This will effect all your percentage calculating while using the
>   modified library!!

Comment: No problem! I have upcoming work with percentages, too, so i had to look at this anyway. ;)

Comment: Then I'm glad I did not keep you from your work then.